# Dijit Tree filtering and search not working on ObjectStoreModel

Tags: tree, dojo, store, dijit.tree

I have created a dijit tree and a textbox and I want to filter the tree nodes based on keywords provided in textbox. I implemented the solution provided in another question but it does not seem to work. When the user enter some word in textbox the tree is re-populated with same data.

[dijit.Tree search and refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911895/dijit-tree-search-and-refresh)

**Following is my code:**

```
require(["dijit/form/TextBox","dojo/store/Memory","dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel","dijit/Tree","dojo/domReady!"],     function(TextBox, MemoryStore, ObjectStoreModel, Tree) {

var searchBox = new TextBox({
    placeHolder: "[  Type here to search  ]"
}, "searchBox");

searchBox.on("blur", function() {
    tree.model.store.query({
        name: "*" + searchBox.value + "*"
    });

 /*the below approach has been taken from the other question*/
    tree.model.store.clearOnClose = true;
    /*tree.model.store.close(); //This is not working?*/
    delete tree._itemNodesMap;
    tree._itemNodesMap = {};
    tree.rootNode.state = "UNCHECKED";
    delete tree.model.root.children;
    tree.model.root.children = null;
    tree.rootNode.destroyRecursive();
    tree.model.constructor(tree.model)
    tree.postMixInProperties();
    tree._load();

});

var store = new MemoryStore({
    idProperty: "id",
    getChildren: function(object) {
        return this.query({
            parent: object.id
        });
    },
    data: [{
        id: "0",
        name: "Root Node",
        parent: null
    }, {
        id: "1",
        name: "File",
        parent: "0"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        name: "System",
        parent: "0"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        name: "Diagnosis",
        parent: "0"
    }, {
        id: "4",
        name: "Management",
        parent: "0"
    }]
});

var model = new ObjectStoreModel({
    store: store,
    query: {
        id: "0"
    }
});

var tree = new Tree({
    model: model,
    showRoot: false
}, "treeDiv");

tree.startup();

});
```

**See the example code at JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xLfdhnrf/16/

The tree and textbox is rendering fine only search is not working, any suggestions? Also why the EXPAND (+) sign is showing with leaf nodes?

[image: Snapshot of Filterable Tree]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added a custom property to the data of model. It is named `keep` and it is in charge of the filtering. Each item of the data have this property. If `keep` is `true` the item will be visible. if `keep` is `false` the item will be hidden.
When the input blurs, `keep` is updated and the tree is re-created.
In order to keep the tree structure, if an item is matching the text, we recursively mark all it's parent as `keep`, even if they are not matching (otherwise you would not see the item itself)
I commented some unneeded lines for the tree re-creation.

As you can see, the `keep` is used in

```
    getChildren: function(object) {
        return this.query({
            parent: object.id,
            keep: true
        });
    },
```

This is how the tree get filtered.

I have created a method `mayHaveChildren` in the model. If this method return `true` you have an expandable node. If it returns `false` you have a normal node. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/tree/Model.html for details.
`mayHaveChildren` return value is based on a store query.

Finally, I used regular expression instead of plain string so the match is case insensitive.

```js
require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", "dijit/Tree", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TextBox, MemoryStore, ObjectStoreModel, Tree) {
    var searchBox = new TextBox({
        placeHolder: "[  Type here to search  ]"
    }, "searchBox");
    searchBox.on("blur", function() {
        var includeParent = function(itemId) {
          tree.model.store.query({
            id: itemId
          }).forEach(function(item) {
            item.keep = true;
            //and we include all parent tree
            includeParent(item.parent);
        });
        }
      
        //reset all node, first we exlude them all
        tree.model.store.query().forEach(function(item) {
          item.keep = false;
        });
        //then we include only the one matching
        tree.model.store.query({
           name: new RegExp('.*' + searchBox.value + '.*', 'i')
        }).forEach(function(item) {
          item.keep = true;
          //and we include all parent tree
          includeParent(item.parent);
        });
        

        //delete tree._itemNodesMap;
        //tree._itemNodesMap = {};
        //tree.rootNode.state = "UNCHECKED";
        //delete tree.model.root.children;
        //tree.model.root.children = null;
        tree.rootNode.destroyRecursive();
        tree.model.constructor(tree.model)
        tree.postMixInProperties();
        tree._load();
    });

    var store = new MemoryStore({
        idProperty: "id",
        getChildren: function(object) {
            return this.query({
                parent: object.id,
                keep: true
            });
        },
        data: [{
            id: "0",
            name: "Root Node",
            parent: null,
            keep: true
        }, {
            id: "1",
            name: "File",
            parent: "0",
            keep: true
        }, {
            id: "2",
            name: "System",
            parent: "0",
            keep: true
        }, {
            id: "3",
            name: "Diagnosis",
            parent: "0",
            keep: true
        }, {
            id: "4",
            name: "Management",
            parent: "0",
            keep: true
        },
        {
            id: "5",
            name: "New",
            parent: "1",
            keep: true
        },
        {
            id: "6",
            name: "Open",
            parent: "1",
            keep: true
        },
        {
            id: "7",
            name: "Import",
            parent: "1",
            keep: true
        }]
    });

    var model = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: store,
        query: {
            id: "0"
        },
        mayHaveChildren: function (item) { return store.query({parent: item.id}).length > 0; }
    });

    var tree = new Tree({
        model: model,
        showRoot: false
    }, "treeDiv");

    tree.startup();

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">


<body class="claro">
<div id="searchBox"></div>
<div id="treeDiv"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: The code works fine for single level menu. When I add child nodes then it does not display them because "mayHaveChildren" return false. However if I return true instead of false then it displays child nodes but filter works for only top level nodes. If Child nodes can be shown and filtered then my issue will resolve and I can accept the answer. See the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xLfdhnrf/26/ Check by returning "true" in "mayHaveChildren" to display child nodes of tree.

Comment: The updated code fulfill all requirements. Thanks for the answer.