# dijit.Tree Folders appear with a icon PLUS even if no children are present

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I am using the following code to render a dijit.Tree, as you can see from the picture I have these issues:

- The folder are marked with the "plus icon", but not children are present for any node.
- If I click on a folder the "plus icon" disappear (should never be there in first place).

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
   this._tree = new Tree({
        model: this._model,
        showRoot: false,
        autoExpand: false,
        persist: false,
        getLabel: function (item) {
            return item.name;
        }
    });
    this._tree.placeAt(this.node);
    this._tree.startup();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the method `mayHaveChildren` of the model.
You have to override this method to make it "smarter"...
See : https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/store_driven_tree/

> mayHaveChildren(object) - Indicates whether or not an object may have children (prior to actually loading the children)

You can refer to this for an example:
[Dijit Tree filtering and search not working on ObjectStoreModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769402/dijit-tree-filtering-and-search-not-working-on-objectstoremodel/31835036#31835036)